# What is the property of the graphical representation of a transitive relation?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, relations

- A *reflexive* binary relation has a graphical representation in the Cartesian plane which has the line $y = x$.
- A *symmetric* binary relation has a graphical representation in the Cartesian plane which is symmetric around the line $y = x$.

Likewise, what is the property of the graphical representation in the Cartesian plane of a *transitive* binary relation?

Comment: It's probably worth stating that these characterizations are specific to binary relations over the reals.

Comment: Well, not too easily describable property: pick a point $P=(x,y)\in R$ and draw a horizontal line through it, let $Q=(y,y)$ be the intersection of this line with the diagonal, and draw a vertical line $e$ through $Q$. For each point of $R$ in $e$, its horizontal translation to the vertical line through $P$ will be also in $R$.

Comment: @Berci Yes that is what I observed too, and I am wondering if there is a more intuitive way to describe that property.